# How can I print text to a webpage every second?

Tags: php

I want to make a website write a message every second.

```
<?php echo '111';?>
```

How can do this?

Comment: Do you want the script to run every second? Try [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Do you want a single script to send the browser something new to print once a second? Try [`sleep()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php). Note that PHP can't control when a browser renders the data it's sent, only how often that data is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the user to see a message every second in their browser, this isn't doable in PHP. PHP is a server-side language, meaning that by the time the page reaches the browser, PHP's work is done.

You'll need a client-side language such as Javascript to accomplish this, using something like setTimeout: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

---

Edit after OP's clarification:

If instead what you want is to execute the script once every X seconds, then you should look into [cron](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference). You can use cron to schedule your script to run as often as you desire.

So an example of how it might work is:

1. You write a script that sends an email once
2. You set your crontab to execute your script, say, once every hour
3. Every hour, cron will execute your script, sending you an email

Comment: thanks , but I want it works in server , because I want every second send message for me , but I want to know how can use it in php

Comment: So you want a PHP script to send a message to you via what? Via email or via a webpage?

Comment: webpage <?php mail('abosami2000@gmail.com', 'Hi', 'How are you ... etc');?>

Comment: @AboSami Okay, edited my answer following your clarification on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot really do it with PHP.  Instead, this would be accomplished with Javascript. If the message to be displayed must be supplied by the server, it complicates things significantly, requiring AJAX transactions.  However, if the messages are predefined or can be calculated on the fly, it is fairly straightforward:

```
<div id='someId'>Message will go here</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var textSpace = document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML;
  var refreshTimeout = setInterval(function() {
     // every second, add another ' message' into the element
     textSpace = textSpace + ' message';
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in a loop like follows

```
    while(1)
    {
    echo 111;
    sleep(1);
    }
```

Comment: Note some browsers (IE ) will require a certain about of data to be sent before it displays any of the information. (also you may need to configure the script/server to flush cache before it sends out partially completed pages)

Comment: it is still looding nothing happen

Comment: As what was mentioned in other posts here, it is not ideal for PHP to do this, and this solution will require some flushing either therough server config, or possible with using ob_flush() and flush() functions

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not well suited for what you want to do.  Instead, use Javascript and the function `setInterval(functionName, 1000)`, where `functionName` is a Javascript function that writes the message that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to refresh the page automatically:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<?php echo '111';?>
```